# Cant find after_create when I do the test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, factory-bot

I am using this factory to create Quizes for my test:

```
  factory :quiz_with_two_choices_first_correct, :class => Quiz do |i|
    quiz_type Quiz.SINGLE_ANSWER_CHOICE
    weight 1

    i.after_create do |quiz|
      quiz.quiz_choices = [FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_choice, :body=>'Quiz Choice 1', :is_correct=>true, :position=>1),
                           FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_choice, :body=>'Quiz Choice 2', :is_correct=>false, :position=>2)]
    end
  end
```

In my Quiz model I have:

```
  after_create { |record|

    if !current_unit.nil? then
      if current_unit_type.eql? FinalExam.to_s then
        current_unit.total_weights=
            current_unit.total_weights+ record.weight
        current_unit.save
      end
    end

  }
```

But when I try to test, I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: quiz= FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_with_two_choices)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `after_create=' for #<Quiz:0xb50075c>
```

Here is my test:

```
describe "When a final question is created" do

  it "can't be deleted if any student is enrolled to it" do
    quiz= FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_with_two_choices)
    final_question = FinalExamQuestion.create(:quiz_id=>quiz.id)
    quiz_count_before_try_to_destroy_quiz= Quiz.all.count
    quiz.destroy
    Quiz.all.count.should == quiz_count_before_try_to_destroy_quiz
  end
  it "can be deleted if there isn't any student enrolled to it" do
    quiz= FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_with_two_choices)
    quiz_count_before_try_to_destroy_quiz= Quiz.all.count
    quiz.destroy
    Quiz.all.count.should_not == quiz_count_before_try_to_destroy_quiz
  end
end
```

So, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your assignment of an after create block inside the factory:

```
i.after_create do |quiz|
      quiz.quiz_choices = [FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_choice, :body=>'Quiz Choice 1', :is_correct=>true, :position=>1),
                           FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_choice, :body=>'Quiz Choice 2', :is_correct=>false, :position=>2)]
    end
```

This tries to run `quiz.after_create=` and obviously there is no such method for a quiz instance.

As a solution you can try and use the following syntax which is valid with factory girl:

```
  after(:create) do |quiz|
    # Do your quiz stuff here
  end
```